# Error in longitude contour near the pole MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, latitude-longitude

I want to plot lat/lon contours at the south pole, my data consists of grid cells, each with a lat and lon value. My problem is where the longitudes "meets" each other, as you can see in the picture, the vertical longitude in the lower part of the picture have a lot of lines on top of each other.[image: lat/lon contours]
Does anyone know how to remove them? Here is my code:

```
coldiv = -57.5:2.5:-7.5; 
min_pr = coldiv(1); max_pr = coldiv(end);
cmap = [0 0 0.4; 0 0 0.7; 0 0 1; 0 0.2 1; 0 0.4 1; 0 0.6 1; 0 0.8 1; 0 1 1;         
0 1 0; 0.6 0.8 0; 0.6 0.6 0; 0.6 0.4 0; 0.6 0.2 0; 1 0 0];


x = linspace(1,length(coldiv)-2,length(cmap));
xi = 1:length(coldiv)-2;
cmap = interp1(x,cmap,xi);
cmap = [0. 0. 0.; cmap];
fig=figure();
set(fig, 'Position', [10 10 1500 700])


pcolor(mean(tas_ann_DMI_hist_tot,3))
shading flat
hold on;
contour(flip_lat_DMI, 'k','ShowText','on');
contour(flip_lon_DMI, 'k','ShowText','on');
caxis([min_pr max_pr]);colormap(cmap);
axesHandles = findobj(get(fig,'Children'), 'flat','Type','axes');
axis(axesHandles,'square')
set(gca,'YTick',[]);
set(gca,'XTick',[]);
```

Comment: Could you show what your desired output is?

Comment: Ideally I want all the lines that are on  top of each other removed. So there are line vertical lines between longitude -150 and 150

Comment: What about manually drawing meridians with `line` or `plot` ? Drawing contour lines on longitudes is bound to fail where they suddenly drop from 180° to -180°. You may have to label meridians manually, though.

Comment: Thanks Brice, I will try that

Comment: Can you put a [mcve]? Give us some random data for the variables not defined in your code

Comment: Can't you use the `polaraxes` function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

```
flip_lon_DMI(flip_lon_DMI<-160) = NaN;
flip_lon_DMI(flip_lon_DMI>190) = NaN;

...

contour(flip_lat_DMI,-90:5:-60,'k--','ShowText','on','Color',[.5 .5 .5]);
contour(flip_lon_DMI,-150:30:180,'k--','ShowText','on','Color',[.5 .5 .5]);
```